# WinForms DataGridView instantly save to Entity Framework table

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

Losing the plot here with what I hear to be a simple operation. I have a basic Winforms application with just a DataGridView in the center.

I have a table in SQL Server connected with Entity Framework db-first.

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        Global.db.*Entity*.Load();
        bs.DataSource = Global.db.*Entity*.Local.ToBindingList() ;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Now my understanding is when I launch this and change a value in any of the cells it automatically updates the DB in the background!

But no dice.

Anyone know a way of doing this without updating the whole table each time (this is going to be a big table)

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: It doesn't update database automatically. It updates elements of the `BindingList` which are entities of the `DbSet`. You can save changes to database by calling `SaveChange` method of your `DbContext` object which is used to load data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Reza, What was missing..

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Global.db.SaveChanges();
    }
```